# Using same database for multiple wordpress websites

Tags: wordpress

I want to use the same database for multiple WordPress sites. The products should be same in both sites but front end differs. 
Is there any way i can accomplish this? So that i can save fhe database of products and just use to create another site without wasting time to upload products.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to use One Database for Multiple Wordpress setup on different Domains because Wordpress Database stores SITE URL in wp_options and wp_posts frequently.
And there is no option to switch SITE URL dynamically.

One option I can think of is running a script that executed daily in CRON, script clones everything from one database to another AND also update URLs in the database dynamically.
That should copy all the content you add in one database to another.

Let me know if you have more concerns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be possible unless you were to change the prefix of the tables for one WP install, but then you still wouldn't have the same content on both sites.

Maybe try out WordPress Multisites, I think this might help you in this instance.